# How to acces all the array elements in geometry shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

These are the  four points to be drawn.

```
m_points = { -0.905 , 0.905 ,   // Top Left
               0.905 , 0.905 ,   // Top Right
               0.905 , -0.905 ,   // Bottom Left
              -0.905 , -0.905   // Bottom Right
    };
```

and than calling the draw arrays.

```
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 4);
```

According to the documents the ->   The geometry shader receives all vertices of a primitive as its input.

In the Geometry i want a line to be drawn from one point to another using this code.

```
#version 400 core
layout (points) in;
layout (line_strip, max_vertices = 4) out;
  

    void main() {    
        gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position ; 
        EmitVertex();
    
        gl_Position = gl_in[1].gl_Position ;
        EmitVertex();
    
        gl_Position = gl_in[2].gl_Position ;
        EmitVertex();
    
        gl_Position = gl_in[3].gl_Position ;
        EmitVertex();
        
        EndPrimitive();
    }
```

But shader is throwing the error that array out of bounds , can i get all the four points in the geometry shader ?

Comment: What is the primitive type? A point primitive (`layout (points) in`) has just 1 vertex coordinate.

Comment: @Rabbid76 if i need 4 points at the same time how do i send it to the Geometry shader.

Comment: You need to draw primitives with a different type. See [Geometry Shader - Primitive in/out specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Primitive_in.2Fout_specification). e.g. [`GL_LINES_ADJACENCY`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives).

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you very much i will try with LINE_STRIP_ADJACENCY.